# Were there alternatives In the 1950s to the logistic function for classification?

Tags: logistic, history

I would like to know why logistic function is chosen for classification.

After reading the [original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2983890) developing logistic regression by David Cox, I can understand the benefits of using the logistic function. However, **in the 1950's, were there alternatives to the logistic function could help David Cox?** If there was any, what would it be?

Comment: Not wanting to undermine Sir David's reputation, but I think he would want to underline the contribution of Berkson in 1944 and other work at the same time in similar style. See e.g. https://papers.tinbergen.nl/02119.pdf for some history.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what kind of model you're looking for, I suppose. Interestingly, a well-known discriminative classifier was also developed in the late 1950s - Rosenblatt published his paper on the [Perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) in 1958. However, it's formal properties (the Perceptron convergence theorem) would not be proven until 1962.

For a more classical statistically-flavored approach, Fisher's work on [linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) was published well before Cox's work, in 1936.

Comment: To add to this, Naive Bayes classifier was probably invented pretty early on as well.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point! In theory the groundwork for the Naive Bayes classifier had been laid down as early as the 18th century with the work by Bayes himself, and as a classification technique it must have existed as folk knowledge from sometime in the early 20th century. Interestingly, it seems that the precise first usage in a supervised learning-like setting is hard to pin down: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/origin-of-the-na%C3%AFve-bayes-classifier